# Acceder a la información de una relación

Tags: angular, mongodb, express, mongoose

Tengo dos modelos

```
const walletSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: false},
  amountStart: { type: Number, required: true},
  mount: {type: Number, required: false},
  transfers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Transfers' }],
});
```

y

```
const transferSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  mount: { type: Number, required: true },
  category_id: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Category", required: false },
  description: { type: String, required: false},
  wallet_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"Wallet", required: true}
});
```

Lo que quiero hacer es: Obtener un campo calculado en walletSchema (dinero actual) que sea la cantidad inicial de la wallet restandolo con todas las transferencias suyas.

(tampoco tengo muy claro si así está bien relacionado)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es la solución:

```
walletSchema.aggregate([
        { "$match": { "_id": <theIdOfYourWallet } },
        { $lookup: {
           from: "transfers",
           localField: "transfers",
           foreignField: "_id",
           as: "transferInformation"
         }},
         { $project: {walletMount: {$sum: "$transferInformation.mount"}, amountStart: "$amountStart", transfers:[{transfer:"$transferInformation"}]}}
       ])
```